# Cannot get State & Result Of Remote Celery Worker

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

**My Architecture:**

- **master-machine:**

  RabbitMQ 3.6.5 (broker)

  Redis (backend)

  Flower

  Celery default worker

  Webserver application
- **slave-machine1:**

  Celery default worker
- **slave-machine2:**

  Celery default worker

I'm triggering tasks via Webserver application (from master-machine), for example:
`task_id = task1.delay(1,2,3).id`.

I have an API for retrieving the task status / result (again, from master-machine):

```
result = task1.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
    if result.ready():
        return result.get()

    return result.state
```

where `celery_app` defined exactly as in workers.. (broker, backend..)

**The Problem:** when consumed by default worker of the master-machine it is possible to retrieve the state / result of the task, but when consumed by slave-machines workers I can't seem to retrieve the correct state /result: (`result.state` ==`PENDING` forever).

From Flower which is on the master-machine I can retrieve the correct state / result (`SUCCESS` + actual result).

In addition, the result appears in Redis backend as `SUCCESS`:

```
redis-cli -h master-machine -p 6379 
127.0.0.1:6379> get "celery-task-meta-74de04de-0d4e-45bc-977d-16caab047eed"
    "{\"status\": \"SUCCESS\", \"traceback\": null, \"result\": {123}, \"task_id\": \"74de04de-0d4e-45bc-977d-16caab047eed\", \"children\": []}"
```

Any idea why this happens? I would like to be able to retrieve tasks' state / result including the tasks that run on the slaves-machines.